# How to persist a Blazorise Theme

Tags: c#, blazor, json-serialization, blazorise

I have been using Blazorise to try out an app and am using Themes to control the colour scheme.

I want to allow a user to save their own Theme in the DB and so I need to find a way of serialising it and getting back to the server.

When I use the JSONSerialiser:

```
            string ThemeString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(theme);
```

I get a mountain of errors:
[image]

Not sure if I am doing something stupid here, the Theme object is quite a complex one so maybe I am being over ambitious? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.